# How to convert this sqlcmd script to an Invoke-Sqlcmd script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell, cmd, sqlcmd

I have a SQL script designed to be executed by [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), and a Command script that executes sqlcmd with the correct parameters.

I want to convert the Command script to a PowerShell script that uses [Invoke-Sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) instead of sqlcmd.

The SQL script, the Command script, and the new PowerShell script all live in the directory `C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion`.

#### SQL Script

The SQL script is called `ExampleQuery.sql`. It selects a string literal. The value of the string literal is set by sqlcmd at runtime to the value of the `ComputerName` sqlcmd scripting variable. The code looks like this:

```sql
SELECT '$(ComputerName)';
```

#### Command Script

The command script is called `ExecQuery.cmd`. It calls sqlcmd to execute `ExampleQuery.sql` and sets the value of the scripting variable `ComputerName` to the value of the environment variable `COMPUTERNAME`. The code looks like this:

```sh
sqlcmd -i ExampleQuery.sql -v ComputerName = %COMPUTERNAME%
```

When I open a command prompt, the default working directory is `C:\Users\iain.CORP`. I change the to the directory containing the files, and run the Command script:

```sh
cd C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion
ExecQuery.cmd
```

I see this output:

```sh
---------
SKYPC0083

(1 rows affected)
```

The script successfully selects a string literal set by sqlcmd.

#### PowerShell Script

The PowerShell script is called ExecQuery.ps1. It is supposed to do the same as the command script, using Invoke-Sqlcmd instead of sqlcmd. The code looks like this:

```powershell
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile 'ExampleQuery.sql' -Variable "ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME"
```

When I open a PowerShell prompt, the default working directory is `Z:\`.  I change to the directory containing the files, and run the PowerShell script:

```powershell
cd C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion
.\ExecQuery.ps1
```

I see this output:

```sh
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not find file 'Z:\ExampleQuery.sql'.
At C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion\ExecQuery.ps1:4 char:14
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd <<<<  -InputFile 'ExampleQuery.sql' -Variable "ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

The PowerShell script raises an error because Invoke-Sqlcmd can't find the the input file in the `Z:\` directory, which happens to be the default working directory.

The Command script found the script in the current working directory.

How do I make Invoke-Sqlcmd use the current working directory instead of the default working directory?

Comment: I edited the question to show exactly how I change to the correct directory in each shell. I made a false assumption about how PowerShell uses the working directory. Tomorrow I will expand this comment into an answer, referring to an [article](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/why-the-powershell-working-directory-and-the-powershell-location-aren-t-one-in-the-same) by Alex Angelopoulos explaing the different behavior and a [thread](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/249957-PowerShell-and-the-current-directory/) on MSDN that provides a workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this answer, assume that the directory `C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion` exists and that executing `dir` at that location produces the following output, as implied by the question:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\iain.Corp\SqlcmdQuestion


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        26/09/2012     15:30         27 ExampleQuery.sql
-a---        26/09/2012     15:30         61 ExecQuery.cmd
-a---        26/09/2012     15:34        172 ExecQuery.ps1
```

#### PowerShell ignores the working directory by design

My question has a false premise:

> How do I make Invoke-Sqlcmd use the current working directory instead of the default working directory?

The cmdlet does use the current working directory. The problem is that I didn't change the working directory at all in my PowerShell session.

In PowerShell, `cd` is an alias for the `Set-Location` cmdlet. You can prove this using the `Get-Alias` cmdlet:

```powershell
Get-Alias cd
```

Output:

```sh
CommandType     Name                                                Definition
-----------     ----                                                ----------
Alias           cd                                                  Set-Location
```

[Alex Angelopoulos](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/why-the-powershell-working-directory-and-the-powershell-location-aren-t-one-in-the-same) explains:

> [A]lthough PowerShell's location is analogous to the working directory, the location is not the same thing as the working directory. In fact, PowerShell doesn't touch the working directory.

Set-Location does not set the working directory. It sets the working *location*, which is a similar but distinct concept in PowerShell.

You can prove this by inspecting the working directory using the .NET property [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) after setting the working location using `cd` as in the question:

```powershell
cd C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion
Environment::CurrentDirectory
```

Output:

```powershell
Z:\
```

I would guess this design decision was made to be consistent. The working directory would be undefined when, for example, the working location were set to a registry hive.

#### Invoke-Sqlcmd violates this design principle

Invoke-Sqlcmd violates PowerShell's general design principle to use the working location rather than the working directory. Most cmdlets use the working location to resolve relative paths, but Invoke-Sqlcmd is an exception.

Using the [ILSpy disassembler](http://ilspy.net/) and a little intuition to inspect the containing assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins`, I believe I have found the reason for the error.

I believe that the cmdlet's parameter `-InputFile` is implemented by the method `IncludeFileName`. ILSpy's disassembly of the method looks like this:

```cs
// Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.ExecutionProcessor
public ParserAction IncludeFileName(string fileName, ref IBatchSource pIBatchSource)
{
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        ExecutionProcessor.sqlCmdCmdLet.TerminateCmdLet(new FileNotFoundException(PowerShellStrings.CannotFindPath(fileName), fileName), "ExecutionFailureException", ErrorCategory.ParserError);
        return ParserAction.Abort;
    }
    BatchSourceFile batchSourceFile = new BatchSourceFile(fileName);
    pIBatchSource = batchSourceFile;
    return ParserAction.Continue;
}
```

Invoke-Sqlcmd uses the .NET method `File.Exists` to check whether the specified input file exists. The method's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) remarks that relative paths are resolved using the working directory:

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
>   information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
>   the current working directory. To obtain the current working
>   directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.

This suggests that `File.Exists` would return false in this case, which would cause the error message seen in the question. You can prove this by executing the method directly from the prompt:

```powershell
cd C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion
[IO.File]::Exists('ExecQuery.sql')
```

Output:

```powershell
False
```

The method returns false, so the cmdlet terminates with a 'file not found' error.

#### You can work around the unusual behavior

There are two workarounds for Invoke-Sqlcmd using the working directory instead of the working location to resolve relative paths:

1. Always use an absolute path as the value of the `-InputFile` parameter. [CandiedCode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608335/111424) shows how to do this.
2. Set the working directory and use a relative path.

I solved the problem without side-effects by modifying `ExecQuery.ps1` like this:

```powershell
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

$RestoreValue = [Environment]::CurrentDirectory
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile 'ExampleQuery.sql' -Variable "ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME"
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $RestoreValue
```

I see this output:

```powershell
Column1
-------
SKYPC0083
```

Success!

The new script sets the working directory to match the working location before executing Invoke-Sqlcmd. To avoid unintended side-effects of changing the working directory, the scrtipt restores the working directory value before completing.

Setting the current directory is described in this [Channel 9 thread](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/249957-PowerShell-and-the-current-directory/). The example there uses the [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) method, but I find it simpler to set the property directly.

Comment: I was banging my head on this issue for a whole day.  Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could fully qualify the Inputfile location:

```powershell
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile 'C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion\ExampleQuery.sql' -Variable "ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME"
```

And use a variable to drive the script location:

```powershell
$FileLocation = 'C:\Users\iain.CORP\SqlcmdQuestion\'
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. In the end I would prefer to set the working directory as the cmdlet expects, but I credit you for an acceptable workaround in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12641085/111424).